Milvus backup tool is failing
I am using the latest version of Milvus Backup. When attempting to back up the entire Milvus cluster, the process only backs up a few collections before getting stuck with the following error. Additionally, the meta directory is not created in the bucket.
Error:
[2024/05/21 00:23:51.409 +00:00] [INFO] [core/backup_impl_create_backup.go:517] ["Begin copy data"] [dbName=misc_db] [collectionName=mld_rscls_USA] [segmentNum=637]
[2024/05/21 00:24:14.357 +00:00] [ERROR] [core/backup_impl_create_backup.go:525] ["Fail to fill segment backup info"] [collection_id=448161342919437791] [partition_id=448161342919437792] [segment_id=448161342941988531] [group_id=0] [error="Get empty input path, but segment should not be empty, milvus/s3-access/insert_log/448161342919437791/448161342919437792/448161342941988531/"] [stack="github.com/zilliztech/milvus-backup/core.(BackupContext).backupCollectionExecute\n\t/app/core/backup_impl_create_backup.go:525\ngithub.com/zilliztech/milvus-backup/core.(BackupContext).executeCreateBackup.func2\n\t/app/core/backup_impl_create_backup.go:657\ngithub.com/zilliztech/milvus-backup/internal/common.(WorkerPool).work.func1\n\t/app/internal/common/workerpool.go:70\ngolang.org/x/sync/errgroup.(Group).Go.func1\n\t/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/sync@v0.3.0/errgroup/errgroup.go:75"


You can consider lowering the backup.parallelism.copydata parameter in the backup.yaml configuration file of the tool. You might want to set it to a lower number, such as 8 or 16.
Here's the link to the relevant section in the configuration file:
https://github.com/zilliztech/milvus-backup/blob/6f2556082165379bd40c782e630be812acd8d919/configs/backup.yaml#L52
